# WP child categories of the parent cat

Tags: wordpress

I got sidebar list that I want include list of categories in it. What do I need? I need to list child categories of the parent category.

Sounds messy?

Got categories:
Category 1
 Sub 1
 Sub 2
 Sub 3

I want sub categories to be displayed. When selected Sub 1 display Sub 2 and Sub 3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to start with the Wordpress forums: [WordPress › Support » How to display the child category of a specific parent category](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/284057?replies=8#post-1120489)